# Normalize number between 0 and 1 in user profile

Tags: math

I'm working on user-profile where each term exists in the user-profile have wight and the weight  formulated from set of factors such as (duration, total number of visit ...etc) , I need to normalize the result of their summation to be number between 0 and 1, I performed this equation:

```
(x+y+z+......)/100
```

Where x, y and z are factors. I have suggested this equation to my self (I'm sorry I'm not very good in math :( ), but unfortunately it returns some value more than 1 , so is there any way that can be applied to limit the result of the summation between 0 and 1?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum values of x, y, z, and ... ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the maximum for x,y,z ...etc. Since, their minimum is zero, but the maximum for them is unknown to me.

Comment: If you have some idea of what the normal ranges is, you can cap them.  (e.g. "I know x is usually not more than 20, so I can say `if x > 20 { x = 20;}`.  If you don't have any idea at all, you need to do more than normalize - you need to learn the nature of the numbers you're dealing with.

Comment: I will try to observe my data to know what is the expected maximum number that can be achieved by each factor that I have. A friend told me about method called fusion can contribute to solve such problem. I searched for this method, but I did not find any formula or equation about it. So, do you have any idea about it? Many thanks for your help

Comment: I've never heard the term. It may be Hatton for weighing each factor before adding it, but even if you do that, you need to know the range of values to be able to normalize. Good luck!

Comment: Dear @Scott Mermelstein, Many thanks for your help. I will try to know the range of my factors then apply the method that you have suggested to me. I will let you know if it works with me :).

Comment: Fyi, to anyone reading this... "Hatton" in my previous comment should've been "jargon."  Dang autocorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variables are unbounded, nobody can reach the normalized value 1, because if someone achieved 1, another person with larger factors would exceed 1.

This said, you can transform every factor with a function that maps `[0 +inf[` to `[0 1[`, like `X/(X+a)` or `1-2^(-X/a)`, where `a` is some scaling constant (chosen by you). You will apply this transform to the individual factors and average them, or just apply it to the global sum.

Comment: Dear @Yves Daoust, many thanks for your help. I have applied you solution and it works with me where I did the following : (x+y+z)/((x+y+z)+ a , where I assume that a is constant and it equals 100 , so I wonder whether your solution have formal name or representation that I can reference to it in my report?. Because all equations in my report should have a reference . Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is called an homography.

Comment: Dear @Yves Daoust many thanks for your help again. Do you recommend any website or resource that explain homography and provide a formula for it?. Since, when I searched for the formula I found it sometimes discussed as matrix like this source : http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~c_shu/Courses/comp4900d/notes/homography.pdf  and other times discussed as computer vision like this source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision), where I could not find any resource point homography formula is (X/X+a). continue comment..

Comment: Do you recommend any source support that homography formula is (X/X+a)? Many thanks for your help in advance and sorry for any disturb.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, generally, to normalize, this is what you do:

1. Find the absolute minimum value, and subtract this from your number.  (This may be 0, in which case you can skip this step.)
2. Find the absolute maximum value.  Your total range after step 1 will be from 0..(maximum - minimum).  Divide your number by this value, and everything will be in the range of 0..1.

To spin it back, you do the opposite: take your normalized number, multiply by the range (i.e. max - min), then add back the min.

The reason you're having a problem is because x + y + z + ... has a range that is not 100.

**Example**

If x has a range of 0-10, y has a range of 15-25 and z has a range of 10-25, and your specific values are x = 8, y = 17, z = 12:

```
x + y + z = 8 + 17 + 12 = 37
min = 0 + 15 + 10 = 25
max = 10 + 25 + 25 = 60

so your normalized value is calculated by doing: 
(37 - 25) / (60 - 25) = (12 / 35) = 0.342857 (approximately).
```

To go back from normalized to a composite number, do the opposite:

```
0.342857 * 35 = 11.999995 = 12 once rounded.
12 + 25 = 37
```

Comment: Dear @Scott Mermelstein, thank you very much for this solution. But, there is a problem that I do not know the maximum number for my factors (x,y,z,....etc). So, is there any solution for my situation?. Many thanks in advance